# Getting .ogg audio clip duration

Tags: c++, audio, ogg

I'm using [stb_vorbis.c](https://github.com/nothings/stb) to load/decode .ogg audio files in C++. How do I get the clip's duration in seconds?

Comment: Doesn't `stb_vorbis_stream_length_in_seconds` called on the return of the previously called  `stb_vorbis_open_file` do what you need?

Comment: I can't believe how I could have missed this, thanks! If you convert it into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `stb_vorbis_stream_length_in_seconds` function which takes the result of the `stb_vorbis_open_file` call as the argument.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/ThirdPartyNinjas/NinjaParty/blob/master/Source/Audio/Vorbis.cpp) of how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use libsndfile 
http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/
http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html

easy to use and simple example . you should open your file with this command 
      SNDFILE*  sf_open    (const char *path, int mode, SF_INFO *sfinfo) ;
and then  with this variable sfinfo you can calculate duration by using

sfinfo-> samplerate and sfinfo->sf_count_t